# A plugin is needed to display this content,I have embeded the code in normal html?

Tags: html

A plugin is needed to display this content, I have embeded the code in normal html?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <embed src="video/MOV01546.MPG">
    </body>
</html>
```

My question are:
1.I am going to use normal html embed tag,what plugin i need to install? or what engine i need to call for playing all video format file
2.This is dynamic site administrator  will upload any type of video format, so provide me a solution for this
3.I am going to use normal html embed tag only.
4.I want to know what player will run on all major browser, Firefox,chrome,safari

Comment: which code ?? please paste your code here !

Answer (score 0):

1 - You can work with html5 player :

```
  <video id="example_video_1"  controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"         poster="./prez.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="./oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' /> 
    <source src="./oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
    <source src="./oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' /> 

  </video>
```

2- basic knowledge, you can protect your admin folder with [.htaccess htpasswd](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) (without your code i can't help you more)

3- find system for upload file and you find your basic solution [to upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929023/php-uploading-issue) video. Verify chmod of your media folder... Verify the max memory that your server can take for one execution.

Comment: thank you for your valuable answer, past three days I have tried in html5 video tag only,biggest problem is browser issue, I have tried to install ffmpeg in my windows, i couldnot execute it properly so that only i have planned to do in html,here i want to know which player will support for all type of video format,

Comment: the player support many format but the problem is [the compatibility with chrome,ff, safari etc...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video). You can try with .flv but is a low format... (software : free flv convecter)

Comment: thank you I have downloaded FLVPlayerSetupStubMDV.exe and installed again if i execute in firefox i got the same answer :A plugin is needed to display this content,

Comment: 1- you need flv player (test with the free [fwplayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/pricing/0)) 2- ff need "Adobe Shockwave Player" to see flv but it is installed on your basic ff browser

Comment: correct me if i am wrong,I am going to  restrict in admin panel with the format of mp4,webm,then using html5 video tag+video.js I am going to execute on firefox,or shall i ask admin person to upload only mp4 or webm, guide me thanks for your support

Comment: 1 select video file with URL link/video.flv + link/video.jpeg title = name. 2 i select flash mode in configure player. 3 i paste the code in my html. After you can change the url file,image and title for you other video)

Comment: with webm is html5, y is correct xd, but we need flv for all compatibility browser

Comment: thanks for info my basic question is I have sony camera the video recorded in the camera is MPG FORMAT like wise mp4 and wepm format handled by which device

Comment: Well dude, you can't keep this format for the web. you have two solutions 1- take many source of your video for compatibility with browsers or format flv. If you doesn't want convert your video, upload her on youtube is most easy for you. It is my last answer. bye ;)